# How to print a special char using shell scripting

Tags: shell, sh, special-characters

I'm trying to print some words stored in a list using for loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

list="bla1 bla2 * bla3"

for i in $list
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

I want this output:

```
bla1
bla2
*
bla3
```

Running the script gives:

```
bla1
bla2
[LIST OF FILES]
bla3
```

I want the words stored in the list to be treated as strings, please HELP!

I tried:
`echo "\$i"`
`echo ""$i""`
`echo "'$i'"`
...

It does not work

Comment: It's not a problem with how you invoke `echo`. The expansion happens in the unquoted `$list` in the command `for i in $list`, so changing the quoting on the `echo` invocation can't possibly have any effect.

Comment: Remember, if `/bin/sh` was capable enough to do everything you needed, there wouldn't have been any reason to extend it; the extensions that ksh/bash/etc have universally adopted are generally there because they provide capabilities that aren't available otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice when you need to store lists of arbitrary strings is to use a shell with support for arrays, rather than `/bin/sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

list=( bla1 bla2 "*" bla3 )
for i in "${list[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

...or use the one canonically-available array, the argument list:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -- bla1 bla2 "*" bla3
for i in "$@"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

---

Barring that, you can turn off glob expansion with `set -f`, and turn it back on later (if you need) with `set +f`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -f # prevent * from being replaced with a list of filenames

list='bla1 bla2 * bla3'
for i in $list; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Put $list in double-quotes in the for loop. This stops the shell expansion that happens if no double-quotes are used and makes your list just a list of strings as you expect.

Note this is not to say there are not better shells and methods to use, just shows another way to be aware of :-)

```
$ cat x.sh
#!/bin/sh

list="bla1 bla2 * bla3"

for i in "$list"
do
    echo "$i"
done

$ ./x.sh
bla1 bla2 * bla3
```